# How to debug minidump.mdmp from a different computer with original solution?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, minidump

Developer console of Microsoft Store provides users' minidump.mdmp files for crashes of my published program. I try to debug them by loading the solution with the version used for publishing that exe, and opening that minidump.mdmp file.

Clicking "Debug with Mixed" I get

`Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF9ACCF9269 (ntdll.dll) in minidump.mdmp: 0xC0000374: A heap has been corrupted (parameters: 0x00007FF9ACD627F0).`

so I assume it is not in managed code but call Stack is full with

```
`[Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no binaries loaded for MYPROGRAM.exe]   `
```

so I am not sure it if this is the right procedure. It does not provide me with a breakpoint in my program, or anything else useful. 
Is this the right way to use minidmp files?

If relevant, this is WPF desktop C# program packaged for Store.

Comment: It is a service meant to help developers to get the bugs out of their UWP app.  Reasonably effective, the UWP sandbox helps a lot to provide a stable execution environment and keep the crapware out of a process.  But not out of your WPF app, you do get to find out how horribly messed-up people's machine are.  Nothing you can do about it.

Comment: In general you probably won't get too much information from the dump, but it is worth the while to try out, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/analyzing-a-user-mode-dump-file#windbg